# Django No Reverse Match Error - Nothing is working

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

When rendering a new page, the html form action on that new page is stopping the page from being rendered... even though it has nothing to do with the page itself being rendered (if I remove that one line of HTML code, the page loads just fine). I've been working on solving this problem for over 3 days, tried hundreds of possible solutions, nothing works. Please help

This is the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /newgallery/rodneyadmin
Reverse for 'editgallery' with arguments '('rodneyadmin', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['editgallery/(?P<username>[^/]+)/(?P<new_gallery>[0-9]+)\\Z']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/newgallery/rodneyadmin
Django Version: 4.0
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'editgallery' with arguments '('rodneyadmin', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['editgallery/(?P<username>[^/]+)/(?P<new_gallery>[0-9]+)\\Z']
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 729, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.9.7
Python Path:    
['/Users/rodneyrussell/Desktop/github/Capstone/Capstone',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/rodneyrussell/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 10 Feb 2022 16:41:21 -0500
Error during template rendering

In template /Users/rodneyrussell/Desktop/github/Capstone/Capstone/templates/galleries/newgallery.html, error at line 21
Reverse for 'editgallery' with arguments '('rodneyadmin', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['editgallery/(?P<username>[^/]+)/(?P<new_gallery>[0-9]+)\\Z']
11        Create new gallery
12      </h1>
13    </div>
14  </div>
15  
16  
17  <div class="row mb-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
18    
19      <div class="col-lg-4 col-med-8 col-sm-8 text-primary" style="height: fit-content;">
20  
21        <form action="{% url 'gallery_app:editgallery' user.username new_gallery.id %} " style="font-weight: bolder;" enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST' class='gap-2'>
22       
23          {% csrf_token %}
24  
25  
26          <div class="form-group mb-5">
27            <label style="margin-right: 20px;">Public Gallery</label>
28            {{form.public_gallery}}
29        </div>
30      
31          <div class="form-group mb-5">
```

This is the line of code being highlighted as cause for error (form action):

```
<form action="{% url 'gallery_app:editgallery' user.username new_gallery.id %} " style="font-weight: bolder;" enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST' class='gap-2'>
```

Views.py:

```
@login_required
def newgallery(request, username):

    if request.method == 'GET':
            
        form = NewGalleryForm
        
        context = {
        'form': form,
        'username': username,
        }

        return render(request, 'galleries/newgallery.html', context)

def editgallery(request, username):

    if request.method == "POST":
    
        form = NewGalleryForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            new_gallery = form.save(commit = False)
            ## connect the new gallery with the user (foreign key)
            new_gallery.user = request.user        
            new_gallery.save()
            url = "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?order_direction=desc&offset=0&limit=5"

            params={'owner': new_gallery.wallett_address}
            headers = {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "X-API-KEY": ""
            }
            response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=params)
            response = response.json()["assets"]

            list_of_nfts =  []
            for dictionary in response:
                token_id = dictionary["token_id"]
                token_address = dictionary["asset_contract"]["address"]
                contract_address = 'https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/' + token_address + '/' + token_id + '/'
                name = dictionary["name"]
                if len(name) > 50:
                    name = (name[:50] + '...')
                nft_created_date = dictionary["asset_contract"]["created_date"]
                nft_created_date = nft_created_date[:10]
                nft_created_date = datetime.strptime(nft_created_date, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
                image = dictionary["image_url"]
                description = dictionary["description"]
                if description is not None and '*' in description:
                    head, sep, tail = description.partition('*')
                    description = head
                if description is not None and len(description) > 50:
                    description = (description[:150] + '...')
                if isinstance(description, str) != True:
                    description = 'No description provided'
                link = dictionary["permalink"]
                nft_dict = {
                'contract_address': contract_address,
                'name': name,
                'image': image,
                'description': description,
                'link': link,
                'nft_created_date': nft_created_date,
                }
                list_of_nfts.append(nft_dict)
        

            context = {
            'new_gallery': new_gallery,
            'list_of_nfts': list_of_nfts,
            'raw_nft_data': json.dumps(list_of_nfts),
            'new_gallery_name': new_gallery.gallery_name,
            'user': new_gallery.user,
            username:username,
            }
 
          
            return render(request, 'galleries/editgallery.html', context)
```

New Gallery HTML (page where user enters basic information regarding New Gallery that he or she is creating... when this form is submitted, the user is brought to a page where they can edit the gallery that was just created (by edit, I mean add new NFT's to that gallery):

```
<div class="row mb-3">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 text-primary  d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <h1
      class="homepagetitle mt-4 mb-5"
      style="font-size: 2.4rem; color: rgb(231, 114, 208)"
    >
      Create new gallery
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row mb-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
  
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-med-8 col-sm-8 text-primary" style="height: fit-content;">

      <form action="{% url 'gallery_app:editgallery' user.username new_gallery.id %} " style="font-weight: bolder;" enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST' class='gap-2'>
     
        {% csrf_token %}


        <div class="form-group mb-5">
          <label style="margin-right: 20px;">Public Gallery</label>
          {{form.public_gallery}}
      </div>
    
        <div class="form-group mb-5">
            <label>Gallery Name </label>
            {{form.gallery_name}}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group mb-5">

          <label>Wallett Address</label>   
          
          <span class="hovertext" style="color: rgb(231, 114, 208); font-weight: normal;" data-hover="You will be adding NFT's from this wallet. Max wallet size: 50 NFT's">?</span>
          {{form.wallett_address}}
      </div>

        <div class="form-group mb-5">
            <label style="margin-right: 20px;">Category </label>
            {{form.gallery_category}}
        </div>
  

       
          <button
          type="submit"
          class="btn btn-dark mt-4 mb-4"
          
          style="
          font-size: 1.1rem;
            height: 50px;
            width:fit-content;
          "
        >
          Add NFT's &nbsp <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>
        </button>
      


    </form>



</div>

</div>
```

User Profile HTML (page where user clicks on an a tag to bring them to the the New Gallery HTML (the other HTML I have listed above). That is when the code breaks and gives that error. The url in that a tag is href="{% url 'gallery_app:newgallery' user.username %}":

```
<h1 class="homepagetitle mt-4 mb-5 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="font-size: 2.4rem; color: rgb(231, 114, 208);">
  Hello&nbsp
  <span style="font-size: 2.4rem; color: rgb(231, 114, 208);"
    >{{user.username}}&nbsp<i class="far fa-hand-paper" style="font-size: 2.4rem; color: rgb(231, 114, 208);"></i></span
  >
</h1>
{% endif %}


<div class="row col-12">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="pt-3 profile-image">
      <img
        src="{% static user.avatar.url %}"
        alt="{{user.username}}'s avatar"
        class="rounded-circle shadow"
        height="300"
        width="275"
      />
    </div>
    {% if request.user == user %}
    <span>
      <div class="editicon">
        <a
          href="{% url 'users_app:update' user.username %}"
          style="
            color: rgb(226, 81, 197);
            -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
            text-decoration: none;
          "
        >
          <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </span>
    {% endif %}

    <!-- 'users_app:update' user.username -->

    <table class="table profile-margin">
      <tbody>
        {% if request.user == user %}
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>Name:</td>
          <td>{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>Email:</td>
          <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endif %}
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>Username:</td>
          <td>{{user.username}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>Profile created:</td>
          <td>{{user.date_joined|date}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>Galleries:</td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>Followers:</td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>Following:</td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6">
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}


      <h3 class=" d-flex homepagetitle" style="justify-content:center; margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding:10px; height: 75px; font-size: 2.2rem; color: rgb(231, 114, 208);">
        <i><a class="homepagetitle far fa-plus-square" href="{% url 'gallery_app:newgallery' user.username %}" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 2.2rem; color: rgb(231, 114, 208); position:relative; left: -70px; font-size: 2rem;"></i></a>
           Your Galleries:
      </h3>


   

    {% else %}
    <h3 class=" d-flex justify-content-center homepagetitle" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding:10px; height: 75px; font-size: 2.2rem; color: rgb(231, 114, 208);">
        {{user.username}}'s Galleries:
    </h3>

    {% endif %}

    

    <div class='user-galleries d-flex justify-content-center'  style="background-color: rgb(247, 229, 243); border-radius: 8px;">

      <div class="gallery-posts py-3">
        <table class="table profile-margin" style="color:rgb(231, 114, 208); font-weight: bolder;">
          <tbody>


    {% for gallery in user.newgallery.all %}

    

    <tr>
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <td>{{ gallery.gallery_name }}</td>
      <td>NFT's: 0</td>
    </tr>
        
    {% endfor %}

         
      </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      </div>
        
    </div>



  </div>
</div>
```

Urls.py:

```
app_name = 'gallery_app'


urlpatterns = [
    path('newgallery/<str:username>', views.newgallery, name='newgallery'),
    path('editgallery/<str:username>/<int:gallery_id>', views.editgallery, name='editgallery'),
    path('galleryview/<str:username>/<int:gallery_id>', views.galleryview, name='galleryview'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the url argument new_gallery.id is empty when you render the html template.

update: so the template is called from view newgallery.

In your original code there is 2 things to change:

1. to instantiate the form please add () after NewGalleryForm. Without you just handover a link to the class.
2. in this view/template you do not yet have an instance of newgallery (just the form). So you can not use newgaller.id. Implement a POST branch in newgallery to save it and remove newgallery.id from the form action and point the action back to newgallery view.
3. after saving you have a newgallery instance with an id and you can call the edit view if you need to with newgallery in the context

```
def newgallery(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       # save newgallery here

    if request.method == 'GET':
            
        form = NewGalleryForm()
        
        context = {
        'form': form,
        'username': username,
        }

        return render(request, 'galleries/newgallery.html', context)
```

```
<form action="{% url 'gallery_app:newgallery' user.username %} " style .... >
```

Comment: Exactly. I don't understand why it's empty though, bc it is being passed in the context in that editgallery view

Comment: It does not look like you render that page from the view editgallery. If so you should get an error because the path statement to editgallery provides a gallery_id but the view dors not take it as argument. Are you in fact calling galleryview? You did not provide that view. Can you post the complete error message?

Comment: I edited the original post to include all the information you asked for

Comment: A variation of that helped fix the errors, phew!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the gallery as context into the view that has the edit form. I don't see in the views that you posted that you have a detail view but I do see a detail view url. So I'm assuming you're passing the edit form to your create view instead? That view doesn't return a context with new_gallery as a context variable. I would create a detail view for your gallery instead and pass the edit form, user and gallery as context to the template.

```
Reverse for 'editgallery' with arguments '('rodneyadmin', '')' not found.
```

New context

```
def galleryview(request, username, gallery_id):
    # Logic
    gallery = get_object_or_404(Gallery, pk=gallery_id)
    context = {
    'form': form,
    'username': username,
    'new_gallery': gallery,
    }
    # return an html response with context
```

Also, when you instantiate an unbound form you should add parenthesis after it.

```
form = NewGalleryForm()
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate the response. Maybe I'm missing what you are saying, but the fix you suggested does not seem to be fixing the issue :/

Comment: You have the link to the edit gallery view on your new gallery page which makes no sense. There is no gallery context being passed to that template and therefore new_gallery.id is empty. Plus why would a user go to the new gallery page to edit an existing gallery. You likely want an entirely new detail view / template to show the individual gallery (you already have a url for this). In that view is where you should pass the gallery to the template as context, then on that page link to your edit gallery view. Remove the link to edit gallery from the new gallery page.